# Java :Interface Method's Overriding

Tags: java, methods, interface, static, overriding

```
package chap8;  
 interface Interfaces
 {
     void nMethod();    //   normal method of interface

     default void dMethod() // default method of interface
     { System.out.println("Default Method of Interface"); }

     static void sMethod()  // static method of interface
     { System.out.println(" static method of interface"); }

 } 
 class IClass implements Interfaces
 { 
   public void nMethod()
    { System.out.println("Normal Method of Interface in IClass ");}
    static void sMethod()
    { System.out.println("Does function overrided ?");}
    public void dMethod()
    { System.out.println("default Method of Interface in IClass ");}
 }
 class MainClass
 {
     public static void main(String args[])
     {
        IClass ob =new IClass();

        ob.nMethod();
        ob.sMethod(); // overrided method ??
        ob.dMethod();

        // calling static

         //Interfaces.sMethod //  via Interfaces
        // IClass.sMethod();   // via IClass       (why all these sMethod calling showing error)



     }
 }
```

Question: a) Does sMethod declared in interface overrided by sMethod present in IClass ?

b) why am i not able to call sMethod through Interface and IClass?

Thk fpr help!!!

Answer (score 2):

Refer to oracle documentation on  [default methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) and static methods.

*Extending Interfaces That Contain Default Methods*

When you extend an interface that contains a default method, you can do the following:

1. Not mention the default method at all, which lets your extended interface inherit the default method.
2. Redeclare the default method, which makes it abstract.
3. *Redefine the default method, which overrides it*.

Regarding your queries:

1. If you apply these concepts to your example, your `dMethod` is `overridden` in `IClass`
2. Your `sMethod()` in `IClass` hides `sMethod()` in  `Interfaces`

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your example

```
public class A {
    interface I {
        static void sMethod() {
            System.out.println("In the interface I");
        }
    }
    static class C implements I {
        void sMethod() {
            System.out.println("In the class C");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I.sMethod();
        new C().sMethod();
    }
}
```

prints

```
In the interface I
In the class C
```

> Does sMethod declared in interface overrided by sMethod present in IClass ?

`static` methods are hidden, rather than overridden. This means that calling a static method on a particular class, you will always get than method as it will not follow inheritance and give you an overridden method (in fact it can't because it doesn't use the instance)

> why am i not able to call sMethod through Interface and IClass?

That is not clear to me, see the example above which words as expected.

> you cannot call them any more.

To clarify @Hulk's comment. You can't call them via the instance, but you can call them via the `class` or `interface` which implements them.

Comment: @ Peter Lawrey up to my knowledge static method cant be override then why overriding occurring here?

Comment: @Lalitkumar I missed that, need to revise.

Comment: @ Hulk why does sMethod(which is static)  cant be call through classname.staticmethodname procedure ?